# FitBound in Leaflet calls Zoom

Tags: dictionary, leaflet

We are using Leaflet in our application in that we are facing the below issue.

Fitbound internally calls the Zoom event. How to stop calling the Zoom event after fitbound. Is there any option or callback for Fitbound.

Please give some suggestion to stop zoom on fitbound.

Answer (score 3):

Internally, `fitBounds()` calls `setView()`, which calls `_resetView()`, which will trigger a `zoom` event *only if the zoom level changes*.

There is no way to prevent that. This is by design, to ensure all layers refresh any needed information when the zoom level changes.

If you are annoyed by the map zooming in or out, stop using `fitBounds()` and use `panTo()` instead.

Comment: Tnks a lot.
and it is ture.